# MaterialDesignInXaml ComboBox - Clear button issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui, material-design-in-xaml

I'm building WPF application using MaterialDesignInXaml together with ReactiveUI. I have the following XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FilterViewModel}">
            <ComboBox
                Margin="6,0,6,12"
                materialDesign:HintAssist.HelperText="{Binding Name}"
                materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{Binding Name}"
                materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="True" /// <--- clear button doesn't work!
                ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the corresponding ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public List<FilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; } = new();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Filters = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(x => new FilterViewModel()
        {
            Name = $"Filter {x}",
            Options = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(y => y.ToString()))
        }).ToList();
    }
}

public class FilterViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Options { get; set; } = new();

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
    }

    public string SelectedOption
    {
        get => _selectedOption;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _selectedOption, value);
    }

    private string _selectedOption;
    private string _name;
}
```

This gives me nice three ComboBoxes:

[image: Three ComboBoxes with hint text aligned horizontally where the ComboBox in the middle shows "2" with a "X" clear button to the right.]

The problem is that `ComboBox` clear button has no effect when clicked. It simply dosn't do anything, no error, nothing. Am I missing something here? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in MaterialDesign tracked here on GitHub:

- [Clear button doesnt work on controls directly inside ContentControl.ContentTemplate](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/2510)

The issue is in the [`ClearText.OnClearCommand`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/595f36a7b743c742005118b6117dc7ed68b864a1/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Internal/ClearText.cs#L43) method, which is executed for the [`ClearCommand`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/595f36a7b743c742005118b6117dc7ed68b864a1/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Internal/ClearText.cs#L10) that is bound to the clear button. There it is assumed that the `Source` of the event is the `ComboBox`, but it is the button itself, so the method does not clear anything.

Unfortunately, the `ClearCommand` is hard-wired in the control template, see [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L206):

```
<Button
   x:Name="PART_ClearButton"
   Grid.Column="2"
   Height="Auto"
   Padding="2,0,0,0"
   Command="{x:Static internal:ClearText.ClearCommand}"
   Focusable="False"
   Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}">
```

Consequently, a fix of the clear command would require to copy the [`ClearText`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Internal/ClearText.cs) class, fix the bug, copy all relevant styles for `ComboBox` and use the local fixed version of the command in the control template.

---

**Bonus round:** You can work around this in code, but it is a more or less dirty fix. You can search for the clear button when the `ComboBox` is loaded and reassign a fixed version of the command.

I use the  [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package to encapsulate this fix into a reusable component that can be easily integrated, but you could also use code-behind instead.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Internal;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace SignumsAwesomeApp
{
   public class MaterialDesignComboBoxClearButtonFixBehavior: Behavior<ComboBox>
   {
      private static readonly RoutedCommand ClearCommand = new RoutedCommand();

      protected override void OnAttached()
      {
         base.OnAttached();
         AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
      }

      protected override void OnDetaching()
      {
         base.OnDetaching();
         AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
      }

      private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (!ClearText.GetHandlesClearCommand(AssociatedObject))
            return;

         AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ClearCommand, OnClearCommand));
         FindChild<Button>(AssociatedObject, "PART_ClearButton").Command = ClearCommand;
      }

      private void OnClearCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(ComboBox.TextProperty, null);
         AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, null);
      }

      private static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
         where T : DependencyObject
      {
         if (parent == null)
            return null;

         T foundChild = null;

         var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
         for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
         {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (!(child is T childType))
            {
               foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

               if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
               if (childType is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
               {
                  foundChild = childType;
                  break;
               }
            }
            else
            {
               foundChild = childType;
               break;
            }
         }

         return foundChild;
      }
   }
}
```

The `FindChild` method is from [@CrimsonX answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/6181599) on this question:

- [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/636383/6181599)

You have to add the behavior to your `ComboBox` in XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox ...>
   <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:MaterialDesignComboBoxClearButtonFixBehavior/>
   </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @Signum I have added a fix as behavior which is much simpler than altering all styles.